Rails: problem with handle redirect with turbo_stream in apps
In the application, when creating a feature, it was necessary to add hotwired/turbo-rails.
// app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

//config/importmap.rb
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "trix"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.js"

However, it caused a problem with redirections that I did not understand.
I have controller:
class Cats::ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @cat = Cat.find(params[:reservation][:cat_id])
    @reservation = @cat.build_reservation(reservation_params)

 
      if @reservation.save
        @cat.update(status: :reservation_reported)
        redirect_to root_path # HERE IS PROBLEM
      else
        # respond_to do |format|
        #   format.turbo_stream do
        #     turbo_stream.replace 'cats_reservations_form', Kittens::Reservations::ReservationComponent.new(cat: @cat, reservation: @reservation)
        #   end
        #   format.html { render Kittens::Reservations::ReservationComponent.new(cat: @cat, reservation: @reservation) }
      end
    end
  end

viewComponent app/components/kittens/reservations/reservation_component.html.haml:
= form_with(model: @reservation, local: true) do |form|

  = form.label :start_date
  = form.datetime_field :start_date

  = form.hidden_field :cat_id, value: @cat.id
  -# %span Na emeila dostaniesz numer konta do wplaty zalicznki

  = form.submit 'Send Request' 

My problem:
Before Send Request/action create:
before
After click send request/ action create:
after
Next clicks:
next clicks
next clicks2
I can do something like that:
// app/javascript/application.js
// import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
import "trix"
import "@rails/actiontext"

and then redirect_to root_path its work corectly, but I need turbo in other controller.
Any hints?

looks like you don't wish to take advantage of any turbo features, so disable turbo for this form. data-turbo=false

Yes:
if I add data: { turbo: false } to form:
= form_with(model: @reservation, local: true, data: { turbo: false }) do |form|
turbo will be disabled in the controller.

so does the redirect succeed with turbo disabled?

For this particular case indicated, it is approx.
However, as I see, there are more problems in the application:
For example:
Action :
= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
or
= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, data: {turbo: false, confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ```

and the view is duplicated again when I click.

''' Can't add screenshot '''
